# drupal 6 -----why theme() can't output

Tags: drupal-6, module, themes

the code i put in the mytheme template.php

```
  function mytheme_theme(){
     return array(
       'mytheme_example' => 'example',
         'argument' => array('myvar' => null),
      );
     }
```

the code i put in the node.tpl.php

```
 <?php
$html = "";
$myvar = "hello,world";
 $html .= theme('mytheme_example', myvar);

  return $html;
 ?>
```

the code i put into the example.tpl.php

```
   <div>
   here is the <b><?php print myvar; ?></b>being created.
  </div>
```

i have cleared the cache,but on the node article's page, there is no any output about hello world.

ps:which files i can use the hook_theme, template.php, module file. are there any files i can use this hook?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have declared your hook_theme correctly in template.php so I do not think this is the issue.

I did spot a syntax issue with your node.tpl.php, should it not be:

```
<?php
    $vars = array('myvar' => 'hello, world');
    $html = theme('mytheme_example', $vars);
    return $html;
?>
```

Note the associate array, with the 'myvar' (the variable declared in hook_theme), is being passed in as the key.

Another point, it is standard practice to name the template file the same as the hook name, so I would suggest calling the template mytheme-example.tpl.php.

See [drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme/6) for more information

Comment: i have alter the error that you have pointed.but still can't output the $myvar's value.

Comment: Have updated the solution to reflect an associate array, as I believe this is the issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solved that issue yet.

I would try to declare my theme this way:

```
function mytheme_theme(){
     return array(
       'mytheme_example' => array(
         'arguments' => array('arguments'=>array()),
         'template' => 'example',
       ),
     }
```

That's how I usually do and it works fine on me.

Comment: i have tried your code,but there is still no any output.could you test my code on your local enviroment. thank you.